# Windows Server 2019 Service pack

Tags: windows-server-2019

I wanted to know if there are any service pack releases for Windows Server 2019 as of today. I am not finding the information on Microsoft site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft discontinued service packs for operating systems and many other products. The last operating system service pack was released in February 2011.

The cumulative update for Windows Server 2019 is available here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4537818/windows-10-update-kb4537818